# Включение библиотек в проект cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

Осваиваю cmake и столкнулся вот с какой проблемой:
У меня есть три папки с написанными мною статическими библиотеками. Назовем их a, b и c. Внутри лежат CMakeLists.txt с одноимённым проектами. Особенность в том, что библиотека b включает в себя a, а c включает b. Включают следующим образом:

```
project(c)

find_library(LIB_B b PATHS ../b)

add_library(c STATIC some_file.cpp)

target_link_libraries(c ${LIB_B})
```

Проблема в том, что линковщик при линковке c ругается на то, что не находит тела функций, описанные в a.
Вопрос, что может быть не так? И как этот вопрос проконтролировать?
Просьба не отсылать меня в гугл, поверьте я в нем просидел два дня подряд. Видимо, я просто не знаю что искать.
Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: Думаю, Вам нужно привести полный пример, что бы другие могли воспроизвести Вашу ситуацию

Comment: Я бы и рад, но полный пример достаточно объемен... Я был бы рад, если бы получил в свое распоряжение хоть какие-то методы диагностики процесса. Потому что пока я знаю только message(). Так же возможно, что-то не так с модификаторами доступа PUBLIC, PRIVATE, INTERFACE, пока не понимаю о чем они...

Comment: Да и по большей части я привёл почти весь пример. Разве что в оригинале добавлены тесты и флаги компиляции, а-ля поддержка с++14

Comment: поговаривают, что в clion толи уже запилили, толи готовят отладчик cmake.

Comment: *"почти весь пример"* - в этом примере структура директорий проекта не показана, библиотека b и a не показаны, ошибки линкера в этом примере быть не может, потому что при изготовлении статических библиотек линкер не используется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз у Вас свои библиотеки, то вероятно, что у Вас и в корне CMakeFile.txt должен лежать, в котором будут `add_subdirectory` для каждой библиотеки. Выстраиваем их в нужном порядке и в `target_link_libraries` просто используем имена:

```
target_link_libraries(c b)
```

`find_library` ищет файлы, а не выстраивает зависимости. Т.е. эта функция используется для уже собранных библиотек, а не для внутрипроектных зависимостей.

---

Да, кстати, учтите, что статические библиотеки так не объединяются. Т.е. 2 статических библиотеки в одну большую не будут собираться, для этого нет средств в CMake, только компиляторо-зависимые. Это просто поможет выстроить граф зависимостей.